# Copying data from multiple sheets into 1 sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy specific cells (I106 to I160) from multiple sheets into the first sheet. Each should be copied next to each other in a new column. However it copies the data below each other in 1 column.

Thanks in advance

```
Sub CopyIt()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name <> "All Data" Then
            ws.Range("I106:I160").Copy
            Sheets("All Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It does what you told it to...  Where should the data go?  In a fixed range, or is there existing data and you need to paste the copied data below it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyIt()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, wsData As Worksheet, wb As WorkBook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("All Data")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set c = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'start here
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.name <> wsData.Name Then
            With ws.Range("I106:I160")
                c.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
            Set c = c.offset(0, 1)'next column 
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```